# why ADD COLUMN to kafka table is not supported in Clickhouse

Tags: apache-kafka, clickhouse

I have a problem adding a column to the Kafka queue in ClickHouse.

I've created a table with the command

```
CREATE TABLE my_db.my_queue ON CLUSTER my_cluster
(
    `ts` String,
    .... some other columns
)
ENGINE = Kafka()
SETTINGS 
kafka_broker_list = '172.21.0.3:9092', 
kafka_topic_list = 'my_topic', 
kafka_group_name = 'my_group', 
kafka_format = 'JSONEachRow', 
kafka_row_delimiter = '\n', 
kafka_num_consumers = 1, 
kafka_skip_broken_messages = 10;
```

And then trying to add a column

```
ALTER TABLE my_db.my_queue  ON CLUSTER my_cluster ADD COLUMN new_column String;
```

But getting an error

```
SQL Error [48]: ClickHouse exception, code: 48, host: 172.21.0.4, port: 8123; Code: 48,
e.displayText() = DB::Exception: There was an error on [clickhouse-server:9000]: Code: 48,
e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Alter of type 'ADD COLUMN' is not supported by storage Kafka
(version 20.11.4.13 (official build)) (version 20.11.4.13 (official build))
```

I am not familiar with ClickHouse and any analytical database.
So I am wondering why it is not supported? Or I should add a column in another way?

Answer (score 2):

kafka Engine does not support it.
Just drop the table and create with a new schema.

It does not support `alter` because an author of KafkaEngine does not need it.

Answer (score 2):

A way of supporting messages with different schema from a Kafka queue consists on storing the raw JSON messages like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_db.my_queue ON CLUSTER my_cluster
(
    `message` String
)
ENGINE = Kafka()
SETTINGS 
kafka_broker_list = '172.21.0.3:9092', 
kafka_topic_list = 'my_topic', 
kafka_group_name = 'my_group', 
kafka_format = 'JSONAsString', 
kafka_row_delimiter = '\n', 
kafka_num_consumers = 1, 
kafka_skip_broken_messages = 10;
```

The [JSONAsString](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/formats/#jsonasstring) format will store the raw JSON in the `message` column. This way from the Kafka table you can post-process each new row through materialized views and [JSON functions](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/json-functions/#jsonextractstringjson-indices-or-keys).

For instance:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_db.post_processed_data (
  `ts` String,
  `another_column` String
)
-- use a proper engine
Engine=Log;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_db.my_queue_mv TO my_db.post_processed_data 
AS
SELECT 
    JSONExtractString(message, 'ts') AS ts,
    JSONExtractString(message, 'another_column') AS another_column
FROM my_db.my_queue;
```

If there's any change in the JSON schema of the Kafka queue, you can react accordingly doing an `ALTER TABLE .. ADD COLUMN ..` in the `post_processed_data` table and updating the materialized view accordingly. That way the Kafka table would remain as it is.